# How to find the role of AWS EC2 client?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Just starting from the Java code

```
final AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

What IAM user it's logging in with and which IAM roles that user has?

Comment: Exactly, will edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetCallerIdentityRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetCallerIdentityResult;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AWSSecurityTokenService sts = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        GetCallerIdentityRequest request = new GetCallerIdentityRequest();
        GetCallerIdentityResult response = sts.getCallerIdentity(request);
        String roleArn = response.getArn();

        System.out.println(roleArn);
    }
}
```

Maven `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.327</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

You should get something like the following in `roleArn`:

```
arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxx:assumed-role/ROLE_NAME_HERE/i-INSTANCE_ID_HERE
```

Or:

```
arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/USER_NAME_HERE
```

Comment: I specified com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:1.9.24 in build.gradle, still could not find GetCallerIdentityRequest

Comment: That version seems to be 4 years old. Try the latest. It should be there. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/model/GetCallerIdentityRequest.html

Comment: What to specify in build.gradle (or pom) to make this code compile?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html

Comment: Tried, still does no compile, were you able to compile?

Comment: Yes. I updated the code with all the imports so maybe that would work better for you.

Comment: Not exactly, I need a compilation script - maven or gradle

Comment: Adding maven. Give it a try.

Comment: Tried, still cannot compile GetCallerIdentityRequest. In my gradle I have: "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts",
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.327",

Comment: You should open a new question with all the details. It's really hard to debug an issue with no details and this is a separate build issue.

Comment: kichik, how do you run your example?  If from eclipse then can you show the .classpath file?